# how to get new version from git/sourcetree even if I have local changes?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

My local changes should not conflict in any way, but still I get:

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    ExampleApp/ExampleApp.cs
    ExampleApp/ExampleApp.csproj
    SharedCode/SharedCode.csproj
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

when I try to Pull.

I just want them merged automatically, or in case of conflict do manual merge.

EDIT: my changes should not be in version control. at least not for others to see.

Comment: You must [1] commit your changes into the source control system. Re your "EDIT: my changes should not be in version control. at least not for others to see": that just means that you should keep your changes on a private branch, that you never publish for others to see.  [bitsMix's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37291050/1256452) is probably close or completely correct (I avoid the GUIs myself, hence the qualifier). I will note that it is technically possible to merge without committing ... but this is a bad strategy; making a private branch is a much better move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout -b temp_branch
git add -A
git commit -m 'wip'
git fetch origin
git pull --rebase origin/master`

---

1. click "Branch" button,
2. create a new Branch
3. click "Commit" button,
4. select all "Unstaged files" and write some commit msg.
5. "commit"
6. checkout master branch by double clicking the branch name on the sidebar
7. pull

Comment: it's just basically switch to a new branch, commit everything, switch back, pull. i'm not very familiar with sourcetree, let me download one now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go to your repository location, browse through the commits, and see which are the files giving you a conflict?
Then you can take a backup of the files giving you conflicts, and then merge your changes, maybe using WinMerge.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is because I have no time to learn how to use this. I was hoping that this tool could just do things automatically. Like VS2013 TFS. Not conflicting changes should be easy to merge. I chose to take it to another local folder and make the changes there.